# Adding data to an array read from struct within a loop

Tags: c, arrays, struct

lets's suppose I want to collect data from a struct (which are from different source but all uint 8 data) into an array like:

```
uint8 myArray[10];

myArray[0] = 2;
myArray[1] = date.day;
myArray[2] = date.year;
myArray[3] = date.month;
myArray[4] = softwrare_majornumber;
myArray[5] = softwrare_minor_number;
myArray[6] = 2;
myArray[7] = 5;
myArray[8] = 10;
myArray[9] = versions.header_v2;
```

How to do this within an loop on the fastest way?

Comment: I don't think you can use a loop here. Each assignment statement is unique, so there is no pattern that can be factored into a loop.

Comment: use memcpy to copy the data from your struct to the array

Comment: There is no point in making a loop out of this if the source is completely different in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Omarito you cannot use `memcpy` to reliably copy from the struct to the array as you have no control over where padding bytes are placed. Assignments are required here.

Comment: Why are you putting this into an array in the first place? Arrays should generally be used for uniform data, but each element represents something different. This is what structs are for, just keep the data in the struct.

Comment: Are you just trying to convert the contents of a struct into a sequence of bytes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reduce code duplication or repetitive looking code, you can capture this activity with a macro. As a simple example:

```
#define SET_MY_ARRAY(A, ...) \
    memcpy((A), (uint8_t[]){ __VA_ARGS__ }, sizeof(A))

SET_MY_ARRAY(myArray,
        2, date.day, date.year, date.month,
        softwrare_majornumber, softwrare_minor_number,
        2, 5, 10, versions.header_v2);
```

It is debatable whether this increases readability.

In my testing, your individual initailizations resulted in half as many moves as my version. If initiailization performance is important, you can just capture the individual assignments in the macro instead.